# Confusion Encountered When Self-learning AJAX

Tags: php, ajax

Here's an example taken  from
http://docs.jquery.com/API/1.1/AJAX#.24.post.28_url.2C_params.2C_callback_.29

```
 $.ajax({
   type: "POST",
   url: "some.php",
   data: "name=John&location=Boston",
   success: function(msg){
     alert( "Data Saved: " + msg );
   }
 });
```

So does

```
data: "name=John&location=Boston"
```

assign the value 'John' to the variable $name and 'Boston' to $location in `some.php` ?

Or what does it do...? 
On the website they simply say

"*Save some data to the server and notify the user once it's complete.*"

Comment: Since this is a `post` request, they will be available in `$_POST['name'], $_POST['location']` in the PHP script.  In a `get`, they would appear in `$_GET['name']`, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It makes the browser request the URL

```
some.php
```

with the message body:

```
name=John&location=Boston
```

These will appear as `$_POST['name']` and `$_POST['location']`.

Don't build your data strings by hand though. If you are using jQuery anyway, let it build them for you. It will handle escaping for you automatically.

```
data: { 
    "name": "John", 
    "location": "Boston" 
},
```